# Can I use multiparty for a single route in my express app?

Tags: express, body-parser

I have an Express 3 app that uses bodyParser for most routes. (Most routes only accept multipart.) I have a single route that is going to be parsing files up to 1GB in size which bodyParser can't seem to handle. I would like to use [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) for only this route so I don't have to rewrite the whole API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply middleware to a single route by doing this:

```
var multipartyMiddleware = function (req,res,next){
  //put your code to parse multipart here and call "next" when done
}

app.post('/this/is/a/single/route', multipartyMiddleware, function(req,res){
  //do normal business logic in this route and send the response
})
```

If you need to bypass the multipart parsing in the old `bodyParser` in express 3 you can replace this:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser())
```

with this:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())
```

This works because the source of the bodyParser middleware reveals that it is just a combo of three middleware parsers: `multipart`, `json`, and `urlencoded`.

see the connect 2.X source here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.x/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js#L54

Comment: Great! So, if currently have bodyParser implemented with `app.use(express.bodyParser());`, how will I get bodyParser not to parse this one so that my middleware can catch it? Does that happen automatically, or do I need to make changes to the way bodyParser is implemented?

Comment: good point! I updated the answer to work-around that.  Let me know if there is anything else to clarify.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have one more issue: If I replace `app.use(express.bodyParser())` with two of the three component parts, how do I then get bodyParser to continue to handle all the multipart requests except for those received by the one endpoint in question? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Im not going to be able to give you exact code sample on how to do that because I would need to know all of your current and future routes, but you can use the `path` parameter in the `app.use` method to select anything that is not that route. So in addition to the the 2 middleware parsers, you would do something like `app.use(/<regex-that-selects-everything-but-the-one-route/,express.multipart())`.  Check out how to use regexs with `app.use` here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use